# ag-grid select all group children

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

in my AgGrid component i added this property:

```
onRowClicked={({node, api}) => {
                if(node.isSelected()){
                  console.log("deselected");
                  node.setSelected(false, false);
                } else {
                  node.setSelected(true);
                  console.log("selected, add");
                }
                api.redrawRows()
              }}
```

and for some reason the group children nodes dosn't selected also
i also tried to add this properties `groupSelectsChildren={true}` `suppressRowClickSelection={true}` and still nothing...

and also i want to update the parent group when select / deselect the children nodes (using only ag grid api)

Comment: Hello, are you using Row Grouping, or Tree Selection for your grid? groupSelectsChildren should be your ticket if you are using Row Grouping; however, it does not work for Tree Selection. If the later is the case, let us know and I can further assist

Comment: Have you tried using groupSelectsChildren: true and rowSelection: multiple

Comment: HI @KurtW I am facing the similar issue when using tree selection and groupSelectsChildren. 
Getting this warning in console "groupSelectsChildren does not work with tree data". 
Would you be able to assist ?